# Pictbridge server for wifi DSLR camera?

Tags: printing, canon, camera

I have a Canon 70D camera which can print photos over Wifi to a PictBridge capable printer.  My printer is not PictBridge capable but I would still like the functionality.

Is there a way to make Ubuntu function as a PictBridge *server* so it will capture my prints which I can then probably take from there with scripting to forward the output to my printer?

Free software preferred but a reasonably priced product could be interesting too.

Comment: PictBridge is a proprietary protocol for printers. There is no PictBridge server.

Comment: @user68186 for [wireless pictbridge](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/explore/printing-innovations/wireless-pictbridge) there has to be a server running on the printer.

Comment: @vidarlo It looks like wireless pictbridge is specific to Canon printers. I meant there is no PictBridge server available for Ubuntu. Unless the Canon Printers run a current version of Ubuntu inside. My understanding is the printers run proprietary firmware/software inside them.